# SQL search - part II

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to search on all fields (columns) in an sqlite file, but I'm not getting valid results all the time.  Here's the code.  Should I be trying something different?

```
Select * From session
join sessiontype using(SESSIONTYPEID)
join camera on SESSION.[CameraID] = camera.CameraID
join chemicals on session.[DeveloperID] = chemicals.[ChemicalsID] 
               or session.[FixerID] = chemicals.[ChemicalsID]
join shop on session.[DEVELOPEDBYID] = shop.[ShopID]
join film on session.[FilmID] = film.[FilmID]
join vendor on film.[VendorID] = vendor.[VendorID]
where session.[Identifier] like('%agfa%') 
or session.[Notes] like('%agfa%')
or sessiontype.[SessionTypeName] like('%agfa%')
or camera.[CameraName] like('%agfa%')
or chemicals.[ChemicalsName] like('%agfa%')
or session.[DeveloperTemp] like('%agfa%')
or session.[DeveloperTime] like('%agfa%')
or session.[FixerTemp] like('%agfa%')
or session.[FixerTime] like('%agfa%')
or shop.[ShopName] like('%agfa%')
or session.[StopBathTemp] like('%agfa%')
or session.[StopBathTime] like('%agfa%')
or vendor.[VendorName] like('%agfa%')
order by session.[Identifier], sessiontype.[SessionTypeName], session.[Date]
```

I have only 1 entry that contains 'agfa'.
The following line returns the 1 entry twice:
    join chemicals on session.[DeveloperID] = chemicals.[ChemicalsID] 
               OR session.[FixerID] = chemicals.[ChemicalsID]

The following entry returns no results:
    join chemicals on session.[DeveloperID] = chemicals.[ChemicalsID] 
               AND session.[FixerID] = chemicals.[ChemicalsID]

Removing the line returns the correct 1 entry.

Comment: You will need to post an example of invalid results.

Comment: I have only 1 entry that contains 'agfa'.

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: I edited the original post to show what is expected.

Comment: Then that join matches two rows.

Comment: Not realted with this question, but did you consider using [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html‎)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe you want/need some outer joins?
2. Are you working on Oracle? Once I had a strange issue with the OR clause in JOIN - it worked incorrectly - abybody knew why... Make an experimient by converting the JOINs (which I prefer) into the WHERE clause

Note: OR and LIKE are very expensive operations

Comment: That is not an answer. That should be posted as a comment.

Comment: An OUTER JOIN just for that one line?

Comment: How do I convert JOINs into a WHERE?

Comment: I added the tables to the FROM statement and removed all the JOINs. Wow, what a performance hit! It runs forever.

Comment: You must add `SESSION.[CameraID] = camera.CameraID AND (session.[DeveloperID] = chemicals.[ChemicalsID] OR session.[FixerID] = chemicals.[ChemicalsID]) AND session.[DEVELOPEDBYID] = shop.[ShopID] AND session.[FilmID] = film.[FilmID] AND film.[VendorID] = vendor.[VendorID]` to the WHERE clause